# C: List aliases of current shell (not subshell!)

Tags: c, shell, posix, bash

I'm trying to find all aliases that the current shell possesses (in a C program). I've tried `system("alias")`, `popen("alias", "r")` and `execvp("alias", ...)`, the latter of which doesn't work at all (because `alias` is a shell-specific command) and the first two of which run that command in a **subshell** (which is `sh` and not `bash`) -> there, aliases are disabled because they are defined in my `~/.bashrc`. Executing `bash` and reading the output of `alias` isn't possible either because `bash` will only go to the alias definitions if it is in interactive mode.

If I **do** run `bash` in interactive mode, I get a huge delay time and a prompt output that I want to **avoid**.

Basically, what I want, is to have similar behaviour as `time(1)`. It looks up current aliases without even executing any command! (it will fork only once, that is, for the passed command)

Crawling the Internet was to no avail.

Question: How do I look up all **aliases** in the **current shell**? Will there be any portability issues? If yes, how to avoid them?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. time is a built-in and it can access the aliases which are stored internally to the shell instance that is running. if you need to work out what the shell will execute, you need to run which or something similar.

time isn't doing anything clever or secret. It's just a prefix to the command to make the shell print out some timing information.

Answer (score 2):

I just downloaded and built GNU time on my Mac. To my surprise and chagrin, it doesn't read aliases from the parent bash, whereas the built-in `time` does.

```
$ alias frodo=ls
$ ./time frodo
./time: cannot run frodo: No such file or directory
Command exited with non-zero status 127
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed ?%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 819200maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+59minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ time frodo
AUTHORS    INSTALL      Makefile.in  config.cache    configure*    error.o   getopt.o   getpagesize.h  mkinstalldirs*  resuse.h  stamp-vti    time.c     time.texi  version.texi
COPYING    Makefile     NEWS         config.log      configure.in  getopt.c  getopt1.c  install-sh*    port.h          resuse.o  texinfo.tex  time.info  version.c  wait.h
ChangeLog  Makefile.am  README       config.status*  error.c       getopt.h  getopt1.o  mdate-sh*      resuse.c        stamp-v   time*        time.o     version.o

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.002s
$
```

I suspect there's something undocumented is passing under the table to help the builtin `time` see aliases (or BSD provides something that GNU time won't or can't make use of).

**EDIT:** Prompted by Tom Tanner's answer (+1 Tom), I just realised that `time frodo` doesn't invoke `/usr/bin/time` (as suggested by `which time`), and that explicitly running `/usr/bin/time frodo` also fails, so it must be that entering `time` by itself invokes a bash builtin command.

Comment: +1. A very informative post. Another thing that I've noticed: `time` will only expand aliases in `bash`, not in `sh`. So it might also be a `bash`-specific behaviour. Might `bash` be listening on a socket that can handle `alias` requests (or any requests for that matter)? I didn't find any signs of it on the Internet/my local pc though. This one is quite tricky... Hopefully there might be someone to enlighten us further.

Comment: Just realized this as well. Too bad we were confused by the ambiguity that `time` is not an executable but a bash-command. Welp, there goes my hope!